# Why can't I add (font)color to link with adding it a class?

Tags: css

My css:

```
.menu_2_1 ul {
    float:left;
    list-style-type:none;
}
.menu_2_1 ul li {
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    width:auto;
    height:55px;
    margin-left:20px;
    padding-top:25px;
}
.menu_2_1 ul li a:link, 
.menu_2_1 ul li a:visited, 
.menu_2_1 ul li a:hover, 
.menu_2_1 ul li a:active {
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:1.70em;
    color:grey;
    padding:25px;
}
.activeLink {
    background:lightblue;
    color:red;
    font-size:1.80em;
}
```

My html:

```
<div class="colm menu_2_1">
    <ul>
        <li class="activeLink"><a href="#1">Link1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#2">Link2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#3">Link3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!--colm menu_2_1-->
```

I am just trying to add that "activeLink" class to the links (so that I later on with jQ add and remove that class ). However, that condition **doesn't change the font color** though It does change the text-decoration or font-size..

Why is that? Css Specificity?

Thanks alot!

Comment: You probably have an `a` element in your css that is setting font colour.

Comment: @Adsy : I don't have any other a element..

Comment: @LakshmiPrasanna : That doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already gave the answer.... specificity

`.menu_2_1 ul li a:link` is more specific then `.activeClass`

The solution would be to use `.menu_2_1 ul li.activeLink a`.

Check the [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4rHF3/1/).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to either change your css or html...

change html:

```
<li><a class="activeLink"...
```

change css:

```
.activeLink a{color:#f00;}
```

You may even need to be more specific with your selector as you have other rules targeting the links.

more specific css:

```
div.colm menu_2_1 ul li.activeLink a{}
```

or if you update your html

```
div.colm menu_2_1 ul li a.activeLink{}
```

or if you want to be lazy, you can use !important

like this:

```
.activeLink{color:#f00!important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is back to prioritize, need to change CSS selector to `.menu_2_1 ul li.activeLink a`.

```
.menu_2_1 ul li.activeLink a{
    background:lightblue;
    color:red;
    font-size:1.80em;
}
```

Comment: Explain and provide links to documentation please.

Comment: Don't use `!important` unless you need to override an external stylesheet which you can't overrule using specificity.